# Slack SlackAPIPostOperator not working properly in airflow composer

Tags: airflow, slack, google-cloud-composer

I am trying to send notifications tom slack when DAG run fails in airflow in google cloud composer. The version of airflow used is 1.9 so I cannot use slack webhooks. But when I add my code , i get this strange error : No module named 'slackclient'

I am not sure how to make this work in google cloud composer. I tried installing the slack package by adding PyPi variables in composer. But till now nothing works.
Anybody please help?

My code:

```
from slackclient import SlackClient
from airflow.operators.slack_operator import SlackAPIPostOperator

slack_channel= 'gsdgsdg'
slack_token = 'ssdfhfdrtxcuweiwvbnw54135f543589zdklchvfö'

def task_fail_slack_alert(context):

    slack_msg = \
    """
        :red_circle: Task Failed. 
        *Task*: {task}  
        *Dag*: {dag} 
        *Execution Time*: {exec_date}  
        *Log Url*: {log_url} 
        """.format(task=context.get('task_instance'
        ).task_id, dag=context.get('task_instance').dag_id,
        ti=context.get('task_instance'),
        exec_date=context.get('execution_date'),
        log_url=context.get('task_instance').log_url)

    failed_alert = SlackAPIPostOperator(
            task_id = 'airflow_etl_failed',
            channel = slack_channel,
            token = slack_token,
            text = slack_msg
    )


    return failed_alert.execute(context=context)
```

Answer (score 5):

The `SlackAPIPostOperator` requires the `slackclient` library installed, which is usually done using

`$ pip install apache-airflow[slack]`

BUT as you're running Google Cloud Composer this clearly won't work. Instead, you can install `slackclient` using the environment's PyPI package installer.

Navigate to the

> Google Cloud Console -> Google Cloud Composer -> Your Airflow environment

and then choose the "PYPI PACKAGES" tab. You can then specify the `slackclient` module to be installed, and maybe pin it at a version (`>=1.3.2` ?)